# Is it good practice to declare a DB's column as an Object in a POJO class?

Tags: java, mysql, oop, resultset, pojo

This is an example of my Database,
Customer(idCustomer,Name,email ... )
Product(idProduct,name,price ...)
Order(idOrder,idProduct,idCustomer,...)

How would I declare idProduct in Order Class

```
public class Order{
private int idCustomer ; 
private int idProduct ; 
private int idOrder ;
//Getters and setters
}
```

Or

```
public class Order{ 
private Customer customer ; 
private Product product ; 
private int idOrder ; 
//Getters and Setters  }
```

When I changed the attributes as shown in the second snippet. I faced a problem when using Setters with ResultSet so I created a Customer and Product variable in the loop.

```
public static  List<Order> getAllOrder() {
    List<Order> list=new ArrayList<Order>() ; 
    Customer c = new Customer()  ; 
    Product p = new Product() 
    try { 
        Connection con =DB.getCon() ; 
        java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from Order") ; 
        
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery()   ;
        while (rs.next()) { 
            Order o =new Order() ;
            o.setIdOrder(rs.getInt(1)) ;
            c.setIdCustomer(rs.getInt(2)) ;
            o.setCustomer(c) ; 
            p.setIdProduct(rs.getInt(3)) ;
            c.setProduct(p) ;
            list.add(o) ;} 
        ps.close() ; 
        con.close();
            
        }catch (Exception e ) {System.out.println(e) ; }
        return list ;}
```

The reason I'm doing this is that I want my project to be true to OOP concept and it helps with the JOIN queries so I can retrieve informations that aren't declared in the order class.
Thank you, everyone

Comment: I understand that your code works and you don't have a problem. Then maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for your question? I would just say that you should create new instances of class `Customer` and class `Product` inside the `while` loop. Check if there is any difference in the elements of `list` between creating `Customer` and `Product` objects inside the `while` loop to the way you have it now where you create a single `Customer` object and `Product` object before entering the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, it is best to declare relations as objects instead of just including their Ids. If you find yourself using the Ids without the rest of the object frequently, it may be a good idea to add additional getters that grab just the Id from the object.